# Prevent adding column in Quick edit mode - SharePoint 2013

Tags: css, listview, sharepoint, edit

Q V.1]How to prevent adding new columns ie removing the plus(+) sign in last column, in a QUICK EDIT MODE of a list view of SharePoint?
Using Css I removed the plus sign, but the associated link of add-new-col on plus sign still exists.
Please help

[Updated] V.2  I tried this that almost solved the query...

## spgridcontainer_WPQ4_leftpane_mainTable > tbody > tr > th[title="Add Column"], #spgridcontainer_WPQ4_leftpane_mainTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(12){ display: none;}

But issue with this is - when i edit other columns the keypress focus shifts to row end and gives a cell to edit the value :(

Comment: what css have you used to remove the plus sign?

Comment: " th.ms-addcolumn-span { Display: none; }  " But this just hid the plus sign and not its link to add the column.

Comment: you can use jquery to remove last column from the table

Comment: $("#tableID th:last-child, #tableID td:last-child").remove();

Comment: It didnt work. I tried this ............. #spgridcontainer_WPQ4_leftpane_mainTable > tbody > tr > th[title="Add Column"], #spgridcontainer_WPQ4_leftpane_mainTable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(12) { display: none;}.............. But issue with this is - when i edit other columns the keypress focus shifts to row end and gives a cell to edit the value